# how to write $or query in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

This is how I write Mongo queries in Node.

`query["serviceProvider.type"] = "prepaid";`

but I need to write this query in my Node code which works only in MongoDB CLI. How can I achieve this i.e. I need to query same keys with two different values.

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("test");
db.getCollection("transactions").find(
    { 
        
            
                $or : [
                    { 
                        "serviceProvider.type" : "prepaid"
                    }, 
                    { 
                        "serviceProvider.type" : "dth"
                    }
                ]
            
    }
);
```

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8b057e3a22472facdb89a4"), 
    "customer" : {
        "isCustomerPaid" : true, 
        "customerID" : "", 
        "customer" : ""
    }, 
    "transaction" : {
        "transStatus" : false, 
        "transID" : "15693919985540280", 
        "number" : "8332900803", 
        "amount" : NumberInt(5), 
        "error" : "Something went wrong. Please try again after sometime."
    }, 
    "couponSurvey" : {
        "status" : false, 
        "isEligible" : false
    }, 
    "status" : true, 
    "advisor" : {
        "advisorID" : "BAA0280", 
        "name" : "John BA", 
        "phoneNumber" : 8005301205.0
    }, 
    "serviceProvider" : {
        "type" : "dth", 
        "providerID" : "5bbb42e7a28b1daee826d7ec", 
        "providerName" : "Sun Direct"
    }, 
    "provider" : {
        "refId" : "00", 
        "status" : "fail", 
        "startTime" : ISODate("2019-09-25T06:13:18.554+0000"), 
        "endTime" : ISODate("2019-09-25T06:13:18.554+0000"), 
        "message" : "Invalid Denomination"
    }, 
    "extras" : {
        "imei" : "865300302225654", 
        "latitude" : "99.9385189", 
        "longitude" : "11.5827393"
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-09-25T06:13:18.790+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-09-25T06:13:18.790+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

This is the sample data in database. Please let me know how I can query the parameters I require.

Answer (score 0):

One thing, your query has a type, there is an space after the second `serviceProvider` so the value `dth` is not found.

Also, to create an `$or` query you can simply use the same style:

```js
let findQuery = {}
const q1 = {"serviceProvider.type" : "prepaid"}
const q2 = {"serviceProvider. type" : "dth"}
findQuery['$or'] = [q1,q2]

console.log(findQuery)
```

Or even if you have your values in an array:

```js
const values = ["prepaid","dth"]
let findQuery = {
'$or': values.map(m => {return {"serviceProvider.type":m}} )
}

console.log(findQuery)
```

Or, even... you can use `$regex` to find into that two values:

```js
const values = ["prepaid","dth"]
let findQuery = {
  "serviceProvider.type":{
    '$regex':values.join('|')
  }
}

console.log(findQuery)
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RyQmQpkTErp)

Comment: tried these solutions but I'm getting only prepaid values. I've edited the question, can you please take a look at it again?

Comment: Can you add an example data of your DB please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query if value at a particular key is one of a list of values, instead of bothering with `$or` you can use `$in`.

```
const findQuery = {
  "serviceProvider.type": {
    $in: [
      "prepaid",
      "dth"
    ]
  }
}
```

[Mongoplayground Link Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4LrBiIbRD39)

Comment: I tried this too, still getting only prepaid values. Not understanding why. Also, I need to use that findQuery to query other parameters as well and pass it to an async function further(if this info makes any difference). These queries work perfectly fine in Mongo CLI but not in my Node API code.

Comment: Try logging the query obj before you're making the query and see if it's the same as the query you're making in cli

Comment: Yes, it is the same.